# Are there an infinity of consecutive primes that have no common digit?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, conjectures

Examples: $2$ & $3$, $3$ & $5$, $5$ & $7$, $59$ & $61$, $99999989$ & $100000007$.

I was inspired by the fact that, in English, all consecutive numbers share a common letter, such as seven & eight that share 'e'. See Alex Bellos's Math Puzzle section https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/feb/20/did-you-solve-it-thats-mathematics. Instead I consider consecutive primes and their base representation.

Except for $2$ & $3$, $3$ & $5$ and $5$ & $7$ all such base-$10$ consecutive primes are of the form: $a \times 10^n - b$ and $a \times 10^n + c$ with $1 \le a\le 8$. It is easy to show that $a$ cannot be $9$.
I found $701$ cases below $10^{500}$. A large example is  $1 \times 10^{101}-203\ \ $ & $\ \ 1 \times 10^{101}+3$ and a larger example (with probable primes) is $8 \times 10^{5002}-6243\ \ $ & $\ \ 8 \times 10^{5002}+14481$.

I am pessimistic that the conjecture can be easily proved.
Landau's conjecture that there are infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $p=n^2+1$ remains open.

For other bases: in base $2$ there are no such consecutive primes.
In base $3$ it is easy to show that there are none, except $2$ & $3$.
Base $4$ is the first interesting base.
All cases must be of the form $4^n - b$ and $4^n + c$
(except for $2$ & $3$).
I found only $5$ cases with $n$ = $1$, $4$, $28$, $83$ and $1816$.

*EDIT*: Replaced "disjoint" with the more standard "have no common digits". See the result for squares in [oeis.org/A156981](http://oeis.org/A156981)

Comment: Questions of this nature, inspired by statistics on English language, and transferred to consecutive prime numbers are most probably hard to solve.

Comment: A formatting tip: Don't use math mode for emphasis, that looks terrible. Write single or double asterisks instead of dollar signs in order to get *italic* or **bold**.

Answer (score 5):

Heuristically, we expect the typical gap between primes of $n$ digits to be on the order of  $n$.   When this is much larger than $10^{10}$, it becomes unlikely that the
greatest prime $< a \times 10^{n}$ and the least prime $> a \times 10^{n}$ are disjoint. So I would suspect that there are only finitely many disjoint consecutive primes.  Of course this is not a proof.

Comment: A good heuristic! I wouldn't be surprised if somebody here, well versed with the estimates of analytic number theory, would actually come up with a prediction for the number of disjoint consecutive primes :-)

Comment: Consecutive primes, I understand this as $(P_i,P_{i+1}, ... P_{i+k})$ ; you could change the title to "Infinity of couples of consecutive primes".

Comment: Unfortunately this interesting interpretation for k > 1 only gives six obvious cases (all less than 13) such as 3 & 5 & 7 & 11.

Comment: I don't think that the heuristic precludes the possibility that there are an infinity of "disjoint" consecutive primes such as 10^n-3 and 10^n+1. Note that it is unknown if there are an infinity of Mersenne primes (form: 2^n-1).