# What is the probability that two sequences are disjoint?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that the two sequences: $(a_1,...,a_m)$ and $(b_1,...,b_m)$ are disjoint (have no common element, $a_i \ne b_j$) where all $a_i$ and $b_j$ are chosen uniformly and independently from the integers $\{1, \dots, n\}$?

This problem arises from analyzing  [Are there an infinity of consecutive primes that have no common digit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4649148/are-there-an-infinity-of-consecutive-primes-that-have-no-common-digit)

Let $f(m,n)$ be the required probability. I found that $f(m,2)=2/4^m$, $f(m,3)=6(2^m-1)/9^m$, $f(1,n)=(n-1)/n$ and $f(2,n)=(n-1)(n^2-3n+3)/n^3$.

EDIT: clarified "disjoint", thanks to Adam.

EDIT: Switched order of arguments of $f$, thanks to Joriki.

Comment: I'd first calculate the probability that sequence a has k distinct terms, with the binomial distribution. Then for a given  k, it's easy to calculate the probability that sequence b is disjoint, which is $ P(b_1 \notin a )^m$ is

Comment: @BobLangefeld: I don't see how you can calculate that probability using the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\left\{m\atop k\right\}$ ways to partition the $m$ elements $a_i$ into $k$ subsets, where $\left\{m\atop k\right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). There are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways to assign $k$ different values to such a partition, the probability for the $a_i$ to take exactly those values is $n^{-m}$, and the probability that $(b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ doesn’t contain any of these $k$ values is $n^{-m}(n-k)^m$, and thus the probability for the two tuples to be disjoint is

$$
n^{-2m}\sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n-1)}\left\{m\atop k\right\}\binom nkk!(n-k)^m\;.
$$

Except for the fact that you switched $m$ and $n$ in your special cases, they’re in agreement with this result. For instance, with $\left\{m\atop1\right\}=1$ and $\left\{m\atop2\right\}=2^{m-1}-1$ (there are $2^m$ ways to distribute the $m$ objects over the $2$ parts of the partition; in $2$ of those one of the parts ends up empty; and $2$ copies of each partition are generated, so $\left\{m\atop2\right\}=\frac{2^m-2}2$) we get

\begin{eqnarray}
f(m,3)
&=&
\frac1{9^m}\left(\left\{m\atop1\right\}\cdot3\cdot2^m+\left\{m\atop2\right\}\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1^m\right)
\\
&=&
\frac6{9^m}\left(2^{m-1}+2^{m-1}-1\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{6\left(2^m-1\right)}{9^m}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Very nice application of Stirling numbers. It is extremely worthwhile to add this to Wikipedia's "Application" section for Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: @LewisBaxter: I'm not sure – it's more complicated than the examples currently given there – I think it's a good idea to keep those examples simple. There are lots of applications on this site that might be added there with equal right.